# .htaccess rewrite rule conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Kindly help me out with ReWriteRule... My question is that i have a link that i have to make clean and even made it, but when i apply same ReWriteRule for the other link the data dont display..
For Example:

Link 1 : localhost:8080/domain/index.php?subj=about_us
For this i wrote this rule..
RewriteRule ^(.*).html/?$ index.php?subj=$1 [NC,L]

Link 2 : localhost:8080/domain/brands_content.php?brand=about_brand
For this i wrote this rule..
RewriteRule ^(.*).html/?$ brands_content.php?brand=$1
 [NC,L]

First link rule is perfect and i am getting the clean links, but for the second link the rule is not working, page loaded but no content....

Waiting for ur kind responce....

Answer (score 1):

(answer revised a second time as per our exchange in the comments)

First, don't use the L flag, because you're telling Apache that this is the "last" rule, and it will stop processing.

Second, it is still a bit difficult for me to understand your goal here. Until/unless you can describe your actual goal better, I'm afraid I can't help. Here are a few options, perhaps you can pick one?

**Option one:**

You want users to click a navigation link with src of "index.php?subj=about_us", and have them go to that page, but have the URL bar say "about_us.html".

**Option two:**

You want users to click a navigation link with src of "index.php?subj=about_us", and have them go to the actual page "about_us.html", but still say "index.php?subj=about_us" in the URL bar.

**Option three:**

You want users to click a navigation link with src of "about_us.html", but have them go to the actual page "index.php?subj=about_us" AND see "index.php?subj=about_us" in the URL bar.

**Option four:**

You want users to click a navigation link with src of "index.php?subj=about_us", but have them go to the actual page "about_us.html" AND see "about_us.html" in the URL bar.

If you can tell me which of these is closest to your goal, I'll make one more attempt to help you. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, by the way I m new to this rewriting... As you said I removed $1 from my .htaccess file, the problem is still there... I feel like there some sort of loop is goin on because if I comment the first rule then the second rule works like charm for me.... Any idea??

Comment: Well, actually, I didn't notice before...but you're making the same mistake on the first rule! Make the same change there. :)

Comment: ok now i made the changes as u said, now the 1st rule is:

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/?$ index.php?subj= [NC,L]

and second rule is:

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/?$ brands_content.php?brand= [NC,L]

now both r not working..... I dont know what m i missing here....!

by the way I have uploaded the website temporarily.... The link is as follows:
www.naqqah.com/cavalos

Comment: Hmm. I may have misread your initial post further (assuming you did not edit), in that previously I thought you were checking for specific incoming filenames, but now the rules in the initial post and your last followup show a generic, redundant redirect. Your initial post now shows RewriteRule ^(.*).html/?$ for both rewrite rules, which means the second rule is never reached, as the first rule will handle all incoming .html requests and redirect them...and of course that second rule being ignored is useless anyway, as it matches the first one. I'll revise my answer shortly.

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry for late rep i was busy in restoring the website to its original links that is without prefix (.html)...

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry for late rep i was busy in restoring the website to its original links that is without prefix (.html)...

So now if u now visit to www.naqqash.com/cavalos

so u will find out the actual links as how they r...
as u asked for mapping so all i can tell u is that main links work through the top navigation and the links for brands they work through clicking on the carousel or if u click on the brands on the top navigation...

Comment: Links by top navigation r like this: http://www.naqqash.com/cavalos/index.php?subj=about_us

Links by brands r like this: http://www.naqqash.com/cavalos/brands_content.php?brand=about_cavalleria_toscana

I want to make it clean, plz help....!